# PhoneGap or Cordova lowest SDK version target

Tags: android, cordova

Up until now I have been doing my Cordova development on a **Nexus 5** and **Galaxy S4** which are running **Android 4.4.2** and **4.2.2** respectively.

I recently tried development on a device running 4.0.4 and it wouldn't install. I found out this was due to my manifest which had:

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I quite easily changed the minSdkVersion to one that suited that of **Android 4.0.4 (15)** and it compiled.

I was just wondering though, does anyone know if there are any functions used within **Cordova** or **PhoneGap** which would require an elevated **minSdkVersion**?

Is it only dictated by any plugins or native code that is written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap requires at least Android 2.2. Taken from the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide): "Cordova supports Android 2.2, 2.3, and 4.x." As long as you are above version 7 you are fine. If you're using an HTML5 framework like e.g [sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) you should check their restrictions, too. It makes sense to support the minSDK 10 as there are still many devices (about 20%) of Android users which are running on Gingerbread as you can see in Googles [fragmentation chart.](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

To answer your second question: of course it would be possible that a plugin features functionality which is only available on newer devices. In that case you have to make the decision if you rather go up with your minSDK by locking out users, or you do it without the functionality. It all depends on how well your plugin is written - normally it should also work on devices which don't feature the higher level APIs and react properly (e.g "sorry, your device is too old for that feature get a new one" ;)

Hope that helps!